# Is there a simple synonym for the word "paradoxically"?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

I'm looking for a simpler way to say *paradoxically* in a parenthesis. Would "oddly enough" or "funnily enough" work as substitutes? Is there a shorter and more accurate alternative?

Comment: Yes, you can indeed.

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/synonym/paradoxical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, depending upon the precise context, both “oddly enough” and “funnily enough” can work as synonyms for paradoxically. “Strangely enough” or just “strangely” can work too. “Counterintuitively” is another one, but it’s not simpler or shorter.

Comment: As you say, context is key. A lot of people use "paradoxically" in a rather vague way which doesn't match what a philosopher or logician means by a paradox. Often the person using the word just means "oddly" or "strangely" or something of that ilk, but we don't have much context in the question.